# Dynamics CRM 2011 E-mail Router Capabilities

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, exchange-server

We plan to use Dynamics CRM Online via the browser client, but not the Outlook client.

[Dynamics CRM 2011 E-mail Router](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh699800.aspx) seems to allow Dynamics CRM to connect to Exchange directly, without Outlook as an intermediary.

I can find lots of info about how to install the E-mail router, but not much info about what its capabilities are.

e.g:

If the E-mail router is correctly set up ...

- when a user sends an email via Dynamics CRM (brower client), can we make it appear to be from them, and make it show up in their 'sent' items in their exchange mailbox?
- when a user creates an Appoingment via Dynamics CRM (browser client), is the E-mail router able to transfer that to Exchange?
- similarly, for tasks?

(edited to make first question clearer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the reason for not using Outlook? It is one of the major benefits of Dynamics CRM.

- For common deployments this will not be the case. Mostly there is one outgoing connection defined which passes the mail via smtp or EWS to the mail server.
- There is no integration with the calender (yet, it is planned for [future releases](http://crmpublish.blob.core.windows.net/docs/CRM_SOD_November_2012_FINAL.pdf))
- There is no integration with tasks (yet, it is planned for [future releases](http://crmpublish.blob.core.windows.net/docs/CRM_SOD_November_2012_FINAL.pdf))

The E-Mail router is only responsible for sending and receiving *mails*.

Comment: Thanks, for the first point, I guess I'm asking: If we wanted emails to appear to come from the user, and to show up in the users sent mailbox, is that possible with the E-mail router?

Comment: As to why not outlook; we are considering it, but because of XP+Outlook2007+IE8 platform, Browser client likely to be faster due to imminent Firefox/Chrome compatible Dynamics upgrade.

Comment: You definitely should consider it for its "joined up" way of working, to synchronise contacts, appointments, tasks etc as you already described. Also to allow users to choose to 'track' emails into CRM (including emails they already have stored in Outlook). I would still suggest using the browser for the 'pure' CRM interaction - a hybrid of both clients is often the best approach.

Comment: @codeulike IMHO that is not possible with the standard capabilities of the router. However you could develop a custom adapter which makes use of EWS and drops the mail into the sent box (be aware that I am guessing)